# Give the asymptotic running time in Θ notation

Tags: performance, big-o

Please give the asymptotic running time in Θ notation of the following codes, thanks.

1. `for a = 1 to n do 
       b = 2
       while b < a do 
           b = b + b`
2. `for a = 1 to n do 
       b = 2
       while b < a do
           b = b * b`

I think the answer of second one is Θ(n·log2n).

Comment: Homework questions (as well as others, anyway) are expected to contain research effort. You think something (why?) for the second one, and you don't even try for the first one? That's not how it works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question, looks like intro cs theory homework.